# How to combine a regex with a req.params field in a route?

Tags: node.js, express

I am able to have both `/apply` and `/register` going to the same action using (note it's a regex and not a string):

```
app.get(/apply|register/, (req, res) => {
  // ...
  res.send("OK");
});
```

How do I write the route to make both `"/apply/:id"` and `"/register/:id"` go to the same action?

Comment: Have you tried `/apply|register/:id` ? :)

Comment: @eol Tried, but syntactically incorrect. It's combining a regex with a string?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think `:id` is internally converted to a regex itself, so effectively it would result in a regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an array.

```js
app.get(['/apply/:id', '/register/:id'], (req, res) => {
  // ...
  res.send("OK");
});
```